# How do I repair this bathtub drain plug

Tags: drain, bathtub

I don't understand how to get this working. When workibg properly, you rotate a wheel on the frontof the bathtub and the drain plug would rise to drain or fall to plug. Recently somehow it stopped rising and falling. I can't figureout how to reset it. I feel like I need to fiddle with the screws at the bottom somehow to get the length of the screw right, but I don't know. Can anyone clarify or give some advice.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the drain (without the plug)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a mechanism something like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/Keeney-645PVC-Driven-Stopper-Schedule/dp/B000DZQQQO/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=cable+tub+drain&qid=1563479841&s=gateway&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000DZQQQO)

In that drain hole should be an attachment to a cable that runs to the "wheel" you described.

Comment: That's definitely it. So how do I reconnect it?

Comment: It's probably come loose at the top. In the video linked, you can see that there are two screws on the rear of the upper section. You'll probably need to get in there and re-adjust. We've got a similar system and one of the kids stood on the plug whilst operating it - needless to say, the plug doesn't lift very far now. It's been like that for about 10 years!